# replace parts of a string with x's c++

Tags: c++, string

I'm studying for a test tomorrow and doing a book problem in my C++ textbook.

we have barely done much with strings, but here is my problem.

```
//             name         ss#        username  password

string data = "Santa Claus 454-90-3424 sclaus passwordy"
string data2 = "Morgan Freeman 554-40-1124 mfree passwordx"
```

and I want to write a function that can work on both of those strings if need be that will replace the social security number with xxx-xx-xxxx and the password with all x's for the number of characters in the password. how can I do this with simple string functions?

Comment: I know your comments are probably useful, but I'm much less experienced than you are assuming... :(

Comment: :/ how can I get passwordx or passwordy or pass2 to be all x's based on the number of characters in the password?

Answer (score 2):

Look into tokenization. Separate the whole string by spaces, then replace the third and fifth sets with Xs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `replace_if` function in `algorithm`. (See the documentation and example code [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/replace_if/)). Your problem could be solved like this:

```
  #include <algorithm> // for replace_if
  #include <cctype> // for isdigit

  std::replace_if(data.begin(), data.end(), isdigit, 'x');
  // => Santa Claus xxx-xx-xxxx sclaus passwordy

  std::replace_if(data2.begin(), data2.end(), isdigit, 'x');
  // => Morgan Freeman xxx-xx-xxxx mfree passwordx
```

Comment: thanks for the help! Do you know how I can replace the password with x's too? for example if passwordy was 45Z4Y it would replace it with xxxxx (an x for each character). sorry to bug you again!